# magento advanced catalog product search filter by categories

Tags: php, search, magento

What would be the easiest way to do an advanced catalog search for a product and filter by a category and its sub-categories?  currently I'm searching on a keyword found in the products title or short description or long description.  While this does work when I don't include any categories, I'm lost how to include multiple categories as a filter in my productCollection.

Here is some of the code I'm working w/

```
    /**
     * Retrieve advanced search product collection
     *
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Advanced_Collection
     */
    public function getProductCollection(){
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')             
                ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())            
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addStoreFilter();
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
            /* include category filtering */
/*      
            if ($category = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                $this->_productCollection->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category),true);
            }
*/
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

UPDATE: this is exactly what I'm trying to do - except I need to to search for products in any of the categories not all the categories, [product category search](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/search_and_advanced_search/how_to_add_search_by_multiple_categories_to_advanced_search)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid ,please stop hotlinking. Now see that thread is **NO MORE** !